# how to initiate context menu event in QGraphicsItem from QGraphicsView context menu - PyQt6

Tags: python, qgraphicsview, qmenu, pyqt6

I have a context menu on the QGraphicsView. I cannot activate the context menu of a QTextGraphicsItem. I read that I need to send a scene event to the item, but I cannot find the event needed to make the sendEvent method work.

```
def graphicsview_menu(self, position):
    item = self.ui.graphicsView.itemAt(position)
    if item is not None:
        self.scene.sendEvent(item, event)
        return
    # Menu for blank graphics view area
    menu = QtWidgets.QMenu()
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [`contextMenuPolicy`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#contextMenuPolicy-prop) documentation explains:

> The default value of this property is `Qt::DefaultContextMenu`, which means the `contextMenuEvent()` handler is called. [...] With `Qt::CustomContextMenu`, the signal `customContextMenuRequested()` is emitted.

This means that if you set the custom policy, the graphics view will *not* call `contextMenuEvent()`, which is what actually allows it to eventually send a new graphics context menu event to the item, if it supports it.

The solution is to install an event filter on the *viewport* (which is what actually receives the event in the first place), call the base implementation and return the result of the `event.isAccepted()`, which tells if the event was handled (an item probably showing a menu) or not.

If the event wasn't handled, then the filter will return `False`, which means that the default implementation would be called: the filter was installed on the viewport, `False` will make it ignore the default call and forward it to the `event` of the parent (the view itself), and since the custom policy tells to emit the custom context menu signal, your `graphicsview_menu` function will be actually called:

```
        # somewhere in the __init__
        self.ui.graphicsView.viewport().installEventFilter(self)

    # ...

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if (obj == self.ui.graphicsView.viewport() and 
            event.type() == event.Type.ContextMenu):
                self.ui.graphicsView.contextMenuEvent(event)
                return event.isAccepted()
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)
```

Note: the above obviously assumes that the main class inherits from QWidget (or at least QObject).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. your suggestion works perfectly. Its a bit hard to understand it fully, but I am getting there. Have posted my code sections below in pyqt6 in case anyone else has similar issue.

```
class ViewGraph(QDialog):
    ...
    def __init__(self):
        # Set the scene
        self.scene = GraphicsScene()  # QGraphicsScene class
        self.ui.graphicsView.setScene(self.scene)
        self.ui.graphicsView.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ContextMenuPolicy.CustomContextMenu)
        self.ui.graphicsView.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.graphicsview_menu)
        self.ui.graphicsView.viewport().installEventFilter(self)
        # Load items into scene
        ...

def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
    """ This is required to forward context menu event to graphics view items """

    if obj == self.ui.graphicsView.viewport() and event.type() == event.Type.ContextMenu:
        self.ui.graphicsView.contextMenuEvent(event)
        return event.isAccepted()
    return super().eventFilter(obj, event)

def graphicsview_menu(self, position):
    item = self.ui.graphicsView.itemAt(position)
    if item is not None:
        # Forward contextmenu event to QTextGraphicsItem, etc
        self.scene.sendEvent(item)
        return
    # Menu for blank graphics view area
    menu = QtWidgets.QMenu()
    ...
```

Comment: Please don't create new answers if they just add minimal changes to the provided ones, instead ask for modifications in the comments: I forgot about the Enum name issue of PyQt6 and the `ui` attribute, but those are the only actual differences with this answer.

Comment: OK. Im still learning the correct way to do things here.